# Question about unbounded, real-valued function on closed interval.

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Is the following statement true?  If $f:[a,b]\to [0,\infty)$ is unbounded, then for each $M>0$, there exists $c\in[a,b]$ and $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>M$ whenever $\mid$x-c$\mid<\delta$.  It seems like this should be the case, but I am having difficulty proving it.  Obviously, if $f$ is unbounded, then for any $M>0$, there exists $c\in[a,b]$ where $f(c)>M$.  I want to know if the same can be said for $f(x)$ when $x$ very close to $c$.  I'm trying to use this as part of a proof involving Riemann Integrability and boundedness.  Any pointers in the right direction (whether it's true of false, for starters), would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function on $[0,1]$ by $f(x)=n$ when $x=\frac{1}{n}$ $(n \in \mathbb{N})$, $f(x)=0$ otherwise. It is clearly not bounded, but it equals something which is not zero only in isolated points and not in their neighborhoods. So your statement is not true.

Comment: Great answer but it is important to note that if the function is continuous on $[a,b]$ then the function must be bounded by compactness.

Comment: @michaelhowes, you are right. Somehow I ignored the fact it is a compact set. I'll remove it from my answer then.

Comment: Yeah.  That's great.  Thanks for the answer.